# Could not load file or assembly "project name" or one of its dependencies

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm making a Windows Application project using Visual Studio Ultimate 2010.

Recently, when I open my project, this message is shown:

> Error while trying to run project: Could not load file or assembly "project name" or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

I've removed Visual Studio 2010 from my computer and reinstalled it again; I've even reinstalled my operating system, but this error message is still showing.

I didn't do anything to my project. I need the solution, I've been Googling but I still can't find a fix.

Comment: Do you mind attaching the project. It's quiet strange that it happens after reinstalling the operating system. Or after fresh install, try to create a new windows application. check if console application projects creates succesfully.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
i've made a new single form application, but it still doesn't work. neither does console application. 
i've reinstalled my Operating System even three times, but it isn't helped.

i need more solution. thanks.